# Using @JsonIgnore selectively on parent class fields

Tags: json, serialization, annotations, jackson, jersey

I have a Class `A` which is extended by multiple classes, say Class `B`, Class `C` and Class `D`. 
However I want only Class `D` to ignore super class fields during serialization.
How do I implement this? If I use `@JsonIgnore` annotation on parent Class `A`, all child classes get impacted.

Answer (score 3):

I can see 2 ways:

1 - You can use a `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` to dynamically ignore fields, here we test if the field is from class `A` (see example below when serialising class `C`)

```
class CustomIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {
    @Override
    public boolean hasIgnoreMarker(final AnnotatedMember m) {
        return m.getDeclaringClass() == A.class;
    }  
}
```

2 - You can use the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation to ignore the fields you don't want (see example below on the definition of class `D`)

Then with the following class

```
class A {
    public String fieldA = "a";
}
class B extends A {
    public String fieldB = "b";
}
class C extends A {
    public String fieldC = "c";
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "fieldA" })
class D extends A {
    public String fieldD = "d";
}
```

Then use the ObjectMapper

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    A a = new A();
    String jsonA = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(a);
    System.out.println(jsonA);

    // No filtering, will output all fields
    B b = new B();
    String jsonB = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(b);
    System.out.println(jsonB);

    // Using the CustomIntrospector to filter out fields from class A
    C c = new C();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setAnnotationIntrospector(new CustomIntrospector());
    String jsonC = mapper.writeValueAsString(c);
    System.out.println(jsonC);

    // Using @JsonIgnoreProperties to filter out fields from class A
    D d = new D();
    String jsonD = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(d);
    System.out.println(jsonD);
}
```

outputs

```
{"fieldA":"a"}
{"fieldA":"a","fieldB":"b"}
{"fieldC":"c"}
{"fieldD":"d"}
```

Comment: Second option using @JsonIgnoreProperties seems to be the perfect way to do this.